# Spark Session create in Master Node

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run my spark code from jupyter notebook to my company server. 
So i add the following code

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://host:port") \
.appName("usres information analysis") \
.config("spark.executor.memory","5g") \
.getOrCreate()
```

in my notebook. But i am getting the following error

```
An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Is there any problem with my code?

Comment: Does your code run successfully in local mode?

Comment: yes. i run the code in my local pc successfully